# how I can read child of a xml in VBA word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to know How I can read child of "changeHistory" node in VBA (Word Macro)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RequirementInfo> 
   <V_CUSTMER>abc</V_CUSTMER> 
   <changeHistory>
        <ver>
            <versionNo>1.0</versionNo>
            <vDate>12/11/2010</vDate>
            <desc>desc1</desc>
        </ver>
        <ver>
            <versionNo>2.0</versionNo>
            <vDate>12/11/2011</vDate>
            <desc>desc2</desc>
        </ver>
        <ver>
            <versionNo>3.0</versionNo>
            <vDate>12/11/2012</vDate>
            <desc>desc3</desc>
        </ver>
   </changeHistory>
</RequirementInfo>
```

I am using below code for read root node but I dont know how I can go for child node.

```
For Each curNode In xmlDoc.ChildNodes
    If curNode.NodeType = 1 Then  ' only look at type=NODE_ELEMENT
              For I = 1 To curNode.ChildNodes.Length
                nodeName = curNode.ChildNodes(I - 1).nodeName
                nodeText = curNode.ChildNodes(I - 1).Text
                Debug.Print nodeName
                If nodeName = "changeHistory" Then


                Else
                    ActiveDocument.FormFields(nodeName).Result = nodeText
                End If
            Next
       End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath is the tool to locate nodes in XML documents.

[`selectSingleNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`selectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx) are the DOM API functions that let you use XPath.

For example:

```
Set ver = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//changeHistory/ver[versionNo = '1.0']")

For Each detail In ver.selectNodes("*")
    ActiveDocument.FormFields(detail.nodeName).Result = detail.text
Next detail
```

Comment: I am receiving below error, what should I do? Run-time error '91' Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Have you checked that `ver` is not `Nothing`?`

Comment: As you said that is the problem but I dont know what should I define it. I tried IXMLDOMNode and IXMLDOMSelection but it wasnt right...
I defined Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument26

Comment: `selectSingleNode` returns `Nothing` if the XPath expression did not match any nodes. Double check the expression. (My code was not meant for copy-and-paste, but to give you a hint how to solve your problem. Of course you must adapt it to your situation.)

Comment: at least elaborate your answer abit... I dont know how you select the selectSingleNote parameter and what does it mean using * in select nodes

Comment: I'm not going to turn my answer into an xpath crash course, sorry. There are literally countless xpath tutorials available on the web, please take the time to take one or two of them and read the dochumenation that I've linked to. StackOverflow is here to help you kearn, not to produce ready-to-use code snippets that you don't need to understand.

Comment: anyway, I solve it.. is there any way I can get how many sub tag is available under "changeHistory" or I should read the xml and then identify that? I mean same as your suggestion check how many "ver" tag is available.

Comment: `xmlDoc.selectNodes("//changeHistory/ver").length`. Really, please read through the documentation. Yes, all of it. Yes, it will take a while. So what. *It's your job.* All of these simple questions will be answered there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66025/discussion-between-rima-and-tomalak).

Comment: @tamalak: I just observe that by selecting "//RequirementInfo/changeHistory/ver" only first ver tag will be pars by system and if I select //RequirementInfo/changeHistory all the data come in one line as Node text. my problem was about that part... As you can see in my example I have 3 <ver>  tag.

Comment: Of course, when you use `.selectSingleNode()` you will only get the first matching element. The name of that function kind of implies that. ;)